# Replication : Delete from Master Database

Tags: mysql, replication

Is it possible to delete certain data from Master Database and
retain that data in the slave ?

For, example I want to delete data of before 5 years from master.
And I'm sure that data is not being used in any current transactions.

Will this cause any synchronization problems ?

Is it not recommended ?

I researched for it, but couldn't find any perfect solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother?  Are you running out of disk space on the Master?  Having the same table on both servers, but with different data, is asking for trouble.  Sure, if you are never *writing* to the 'old' data, there *should* not be any trouble.

For deleting "old" data from a large table, `PARTITIONing` is an excellent technique.  I discuss it in [*my blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) .

Comment: Thanks for the Link of your blog. Could you please elaborate this < The partition field should not be the field first in any key. >, Suppose I have a table which has data of financial years code, and I already have an indexs on financial years code with first field of fin code. Now, aint it  possible to have partitions with financial codes ?

Comment: It is 'possible', but usually defeats one purpose of `PARTITIONing`.  A `SELECT` first "prunes" down to the desired partition(s), then uses an index.  If the index starts with the 'partition key', it is partially or wholly wasted.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and show the `SELECT`; I may explain further.  (Start a new thread?)  Perhaps you have a perfectly valid reason for what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

```
set sql_log_bin=0;
<delete_query>;
set sql_log_bin=1;
```

That should take care with the delete on master and will not replicate to the slave.

I'd recommend against this though. I think it's better to transfer data older than 5 years to a separate table then drop the table from the master side and retain the one on the slave.